# How to transfer app from one developer account to another

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-transfer

I have an app on the app store with my developer account and I want to transfer it to another developer account. Apple's website says to click on the Transfer App button under the App Information in Itunes Connect but that button is not appearing for my app.

What should I do?

Comment: I've tried googling your question, and the very first result was the apples documentation.. https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+transfer+app+from+one+developer+account+to+another&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Agent` role, you can find "Transfer App" button.

My Apps > App Store > App Information > Additional Information

[image]

Comment: I also facing the same problem. But i am not getting the Transfer App option as you can see here [link](http://cl.ly/image/0S1s3B3J2Z1F).  I have already checked the Criteria for Transferring an App on iTunes connect.

Comment: @GauravPandey Have Your app been approved at least once ? (Your app at least once there is a need to have been approved.)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Make sure the app meets the criteria for transferring.FOr that please refer to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW7) by apple.

Then use this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW9) to transfer you app also make sure you have the rights to transfer.